# Do all Android games use a single canvas?

Tags: java, android, view, android-canvas

**Should all View objects be redrawn every onDraw() procedure?**

I'm coming from a Flash background so my initial thought was to draw static background images on one layer/canvas and then create another layer on top of that to handle more active animations, but this doesn't seem very practical to setup. Is my train of thought behind Android's View.onDraw() misguided here and is this something I shouldn't even be worrying about?

Edit: To elaborate a bit further on what I'm trying to figure out with the concept of onDraw() - Is there a way to use multiple canvases on a SurfaceView/View that will act as layers so I can manually draw on each individual canvas (to minimize what needs to be 'redrawn') without having to 'redraw' the graphics on other canvases, or is the SurfaceView/View's onDraw() absolutely necessary for updating any visual changes (in which case *everything* is 'redrawn' to the screen)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: Should all View objects be redrawn every onDraw() procedure?

A: No - not necessarily

ALSO: definitely take a look at SurfaceViews:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html

Comment: Thanks Paul, this seems like the direction I needed. However, after going through [this tutorial](http://edu4java.com/androidgame/androidgame4.html) that involves SurfaceView it still raises some questions as it looks as though they're using a single onDraw() on SurfaceView to call other objects' onDraw() and effectively redrawing everything at the same time. Is this just the normal procedure of 'refreshing' the application's graphics or is there a way to have multiple 'layered' surfaces that can be drawn separately?

Answer (score 0):

well, maybe not *all* but a `Canvas` can be considered a Scene.  I use a `Toon` class, containing an `X`,`Y` coordinate, a `Rect` hitbox, and a `Drawable`.  This class `Toon` also has a method:

```
public draw(Canvas c) {
    mDrawable.setBounds(mHitBox);
    mDrawable.draw(c);
}
```

Then, in the `onDraw(Canvas c)` method in the game loop, I just loop through all my `Toon` objects, and call the `draw(c)` method on them.  Try not to manipulate objects  in `onDraw`, they should ideally *only* be drawn.